# Ubuntu HDD clicks then shuts down

Tags: hard-drive

i've had this problem with 2 PC's.
when i install ubuntu, after a couple a days, my hdd clicks and only the hdd shuts doun. ubuntu freezes and theres no option but to force restart it. after the restar the problem repeats after a couple of minutes.
what am i doing wrong? how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mean you tried the same HDD on 2 PCs right? Do you dual-boot either machine? Can you rule out HDD fault with the other OS or `smartctl`? Concurrent HDD failure on 2 machines might be too much of a coincidence, but clicking HDDs need to be taken seriously.

Comment: 2 diferent old HDD on 2 old systems and i dual boot. i used only ubuntu onece but i don't rememer if i had the problem.

Comment: oh and the only way to fix the problem is to reset bios and reinstal windows otherwise it get's to a point that my bios doesn't recognise my hdd

Comment: Thinking out loud here. The symptoms are quite inconsistent. 1) A weak CMOS battery can cause BIOS to lose settings, but should not require a reinstall. This can be verified if your system clock can't remember time, easily remedied with a fresh battery. 2) If it's a firmware bug, you may be able to fix it with a firmware update from the manufacturer, although this is quite unlikely. 3) If Windows runs stable, it could be a problem with a dated Ubuntu release or faulty installation media. Were you able to replicate this problem on different versions of Ubuntu installers?

Comment: my time resets when i unplug the pc... i've used 12.10 and 13.04.

Comment: what got me scratchin' my head is that i've tried it with two diferent PCs (one is dead now) and with two HDDs, one with IDE and one SATA. i thought it would be a comon problem (i'm a newbie) but i've googled it and nada... i really want to ditch windows... :(

Comment: @user207122 We don't know if the symptoms are related, but as a first step, I'd recommend you replace your CMOS battery. It's flat round silver and coin sized. Can't miss it once you crack the case open. Report back with the issue you have after.